# Fresnel biprism experiment - Why is the motion of eyepiece perpendicular to the length of the bench?

Tags: optics, interference

Why is the motion of eyepiece perpendicular to the length of the bench? what does this statement mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the setup of the experiment on an optical bench which runs from left to right.

[image]

The fringes would be formed in the region shown in the diagram.

The fringes can be observed using an eyepiece which can be moved along a line which is perpendicular to the long axis of the optical bench.
The eyepiece might move along a vernier scale so that the fringe separation could be measured.